# Combining two xQuery queries into one

Tags: sql-server, xquery

```
INSERT INTO @TempData
SELECT [ID], '209'
FROM [ProductData].[dbo].[XMLtb] as tb
Where NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
                FROM [ProductData].[dbo].[Properties] p
                WHERE tb.ID = p.ID
    ) 
AND Lang = 'EN' and [XMLcol].exist('/Inventory/Equip[@Cat="Product" and text()[ contains(., "7th gen")] or text()[ contains(., "8th gen")]]') =1


INSERT INTO @TempData
SELECT [ID], '208'
FROM [ProductData].[dbo].[XMLtb] as tb
Where NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
                FROM [ProductData].[dbo].[Properties] p
                WHERE tb.ID = p.ID
    )
AND Lang = 'EN' and [XMLcol].exist('/Inventory/Equip[@Cat="Product" and text()[ contains(., "Device Manager")]]') =1
```

I have these two queries, but they are inefficient because I am parsing through the XML table twice. This is in no way a good stored procedure, so I was wondering if there was a way to combine the two into one. I was thinking of using cross apply, but it wouldn't really work since I don't have boolean columns, so I can't think of a good way to do this.

Comment: please use subquery

Comment: and what about an UNION ALL ?

Comment: You should specify column names for inserts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```sql
INSERT INTO @TempData
SELECT [ID], CASE WHEN
    [XMLcol].exist('/Inventory/Equip[@Cat="Product" and text()[ contains(., "Device Manager")]]') = 1
    THEN 208 ELSE 209 END
FROM [ProductData].[dbo].[XMLtb] as tb
Where NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
                FROM [ProductData].[dbo].[Properties] p
                WHERE tb.ID = p.ID
    ) 
AND Lang = 'EN'
and [XMLcol].exist(
    '/Inventory/Equip[@Cat="Product" and text()[ contains(., "7th gen") or contains(., "8th gen") or contains(., "Device Manager")]]'
) = 1
```

Comment: How would you generalize for three cases? Would you write WHEN THEN WHEN THEN WHEN THEN without the ELSE?

Comment: No I would probably return a value straight out of XQuery with `.query` but sorry can't be bothered working out the syntax. You're welcome to edit that into my answer when you work it out

Comment: It doesn't work when the two cases are valid.